# Local virtual hosts pointing to the same directory

Tags: apache, local, mamp, virtualhost

I have been getting lost amidst forum posts on this issue.

1) I have MAMP (not Pro) Installed

2) My Apache port is set to 8888

3) My Document Root in preferences is set-up to /Users/usr/Sites

I want to set-up multiple local subdomains i.e.

```
private/etc/hosts

127.0.0.1    local1.sitename.com
127.0.0.1    local2.sitename.com
127.0.0.1    local3.sitename.com
```

No that is where the problem arises. In the httpd-vhosts.conf I tried to set up the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@si1tename.com
  DocumentRoot "/Users/usr/Sites/Site1Name“
  ServerName local1.sitename.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@site2name.com
  DocumentRoot "/Users/usr/Sites/Site2Name“
  ServerName local2.sitename.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@site3name.com
  DocumentRoot "/Users/usr/Sites/Site3Name“
  ServerName local3.sitename.com
</VirtualHost>

etc.
```

For some reason all of these subdomains point to the same localhost:8888 document root directory. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You have dublicate `ServerName` in the second virtual host.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't.  It's just a copy/paste typo. Has this got anything to do with the port 8888?

Comment: Port is OK. Do you have some warnings in log?  Try to ask this type of question at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: error log of apache, or see `apachectl configtest`

Comment: This is all I get: `Syntax OK`. By the way I have changed port to 80. Will edit my question.

Comment: I believe you need to change the vhost port from 80 to 8888. Not positive though.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue somehow by simply typing the directive for my virtual hosts as follows"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/usr/Sites/Site2Name/
    ServerName local.Site2Name
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /Users/usr/Sites/Site3Name/
  ServerName local.Site3Name
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't ask me to explain why did this fix the problem though. If anyone knows the answer, let me know.

Comment: I always get this problem with Apache. No feedback or way to debug it. I can see why nginx has taken over