# localhost and subdomain pointing to the same directory

Tags: localhost, subdomain, virtualhost

I am trying to configure a local subdomain but for some reason both my virtual directory and localhost are pointing the same. I tried using the solution in this thread:

[Local virtual hosts pointing to the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557996/local-virtual-hosts-pointing-to-the-same-directory)

But it does not work.

here is the code for my `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/lemmy/Applications/"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/lemmy/Applications/storke/"
    ServerName local.storke
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" com$
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is the code for my `/etc/hosts` file

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost


#Mapping new local hosts

127.0.0.1       local.storke
```

For some reason both local.storke and localhost point to the same (localhost Applications root) directory. In order for me to access the root for storke I need to type in `http://local.storke/storke` or `http://localhost/storke` which makes it pointles to have a virtual directory in the first place.

Any ideas of what may be happening? I am using MAC with MAMP (not the pro version).

Regards

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Nope, no help on this one :-(